# doctrine ordering toMany associations by entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm looking to order a OneToMany association in an entity with the slight caveat that the specific property I'd like to order by isn't within that entity but a property of something that it is associated with.

Sorry for the confusing start, lets attempt to clarify the situation with an example. I'd like to be able to do something akin to:

```
class download
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="entity\download\file", mappedBy="download", indexBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="download_id", referencedColumnName="download_id")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"mime_type.extension" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $files = null;
}
```

Where a `download` has many `files` and each `file` has one `mime_type`

Currently I end up with `ORMException: Unrecognized field: mime_type`

Is this possible or am I simply asking for too much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby

> The DQL Snippet in OrderBy is only allowed to consist of unqualified,
>   unquoted field names and of an optional ASC/DESC positional statement.
>   Multiple Fields are separated by a comma (,). The referenced field
>   names **have to exist on the targetEntity class of the @ManyToMany or
>   @OneToMany annotation**.

In your case `extension` does not exist on the targeted entity (which is `file`). Instead, it exists on the entity `mime_type`, so it's one level too deep. I don't think it's possible to use `@OrderBy` to order by a field multiple levels deep.

You might consider moving the `extension` field (or really all `mime_type` fields) into `file`. And using

```
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"extension" = "ASC"})
```

Comment: That's sort of what I expected but really didn't want to see ;)

Comment: Maybe one day: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1146#issuecomment-190659522 :)

Answer (score 4):

An other solution, useful if you can't change your DB structure: you could apply the OrderBy clause inside a repository, writing a full DQL query where you join all the 3 tables:

```
SELECT d
FROM download AS d
LEFT JOIN files AS f
LEFT JOIN mime_type AS m
ORDER BY m.extension
```